# UserController does not exist in laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Im new to laravel. Can anyone tell me what is the problem here.I am currently doing a user login in laravel 8 by referring a tutorial. But i keep getting **Target class [UserController] does not exist** error

In Usercontroller.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;

class Usercontroller extends Controller
{
   public function getSignup()
   {
        return view('user.signup');

   }
   public function postSignup(Request $request)
   {
        $this->validate($request,[

            'email'=> 'email|required|unique:users',
            'password'=>'required|min:4' 

        ]);


        $user= new User([

           'email'=>$request-> input('email'),
           'password'=> bcrypt($request-> input('password'))

        ]);

        $user-->save();
        return redirect()->route('shop.index');

    }

    }
```

And in route (web.php)

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;


Route::get('/signup',[
    'uses' =>'UserController@getSignup',
    'as'=>'user.signup'
   
]);

Route::post('/signup',[
    'uses' =>'UserController@getSignup',
    'as'=>'user.signup'
   
]);
```

Comment: I cant figure out how this 'uses' and 'as' working in laravel 8

Comment: try this.
Route::get('create_group', 'UserController@getSignup')->name('user.signup');

Comment: after laravel 5.2 this was deprecated and named routing was updated to new syntax 

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#named-routes

Comment: Tried that but not working :(

Comment: Usercontroller is wrong c is small, Make it Capital.  class UserController extends Controller

Comment: file name too  to UserController.php

Comment: @QamarRafhan thank you.I will try

Comment: If you still are facing the issue Please share you skype Id with with me.

Answer (score 1):

Please rename your controller file name
`Usercontroller.php` TO `UserController.php`

and IN `UserController.php`

Rename `class Usercontroller` to `class UserController`

Comment: Changed that but no difference.I think something wrong with the route